# How to change the list format into text file and pass it as argument to a function defined in python?

Tags: python, list, function, corpus

How to pass the two text file as argument to a function defined instead of list as passed as argument?

My code contain three pair of sentences defined in a list. It is passed as argument to function `em_run`.

Now I need to read two corpus, i.e. two separate text file to be read into the function instead of these three pair of sentence.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""An implementation of the IBM Model 1 expectation-maximization algorithm  for learning word alignments."""

from collections import defaultdict
import copy
import itertools
import operator


def em_run(sentence_pairs):
#Run expectation-maximization on a list of pairs of the form
# `(source_tokens, target_tokens)`
# where `source_tokens` is a list of tokens in the source language and
#`target_tokens` is a list of tokens for a translationally equivalent
#sentence in the target language.
#Returns a mapping `(t1, t2) => p` where `t1` is a source-language
#token, `t2` is a target-language token, and the value `p` represents
#$P(t1|t2)$.


source_sentences, target_sentences = zip(*sentence_pairs)
source_vocabulary = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(source_sentences))
target_vocabulary = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(target_sentences))

# Value with which to initialize each conditional probability
uniform_prob = 1.0 / len(source_vocabulary)

conditional_probs_old = None
conditional_probs = {(source_w, target_w): uniform_prob
    for source_w in source_vocabulary
    for target_w in target_vocabulary}

alignments = [[zip(source, target_perm)
    for target_perm in itertools.permutations(target)]
    for source, target in sentence_pairs] 

# Repeat until convergence
i = 0
while conditional_probs_old != conditional_probs:
    conditional_probs_old = copy.copy(conditional_probs)

    alignment_probs = {
        i: {
            tuple(alignment):
            reduce(operator.mul, [conditional_probs[pair]
            for pair in alignment])
            for alignment in sentence_alignments
           }

    for i, sentence_alignments in enumerate(alignments)
    }

# Normalize alignment probabilities
for sentence_idx, sentence_alignments in alignment_probs.iteritems():
    total = float(sum(sentence_alignments.values()))
    probs = {alignment: value / total
        for alignment, value in sentence_alignments.iteritems()}
    alignment_probs[sentence_idx] = probs

# Now join all alignments and begin the maximization step: group
# by target-language word and collect corresponding
# source-language probabilities
word_translations = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))
for sentence_alignments in alignment_probs.itervalues():
    for word_pairs, prob in sentence_alignments.iteritems():
        for source_word, target_word in word_pairs:
            word_translations[target_word][source_word] += prob

# Now calculate new conditional probability mapping, ungrouping
# the `word_translations` tree and normalizing values into
# conditional probabilities
conditional_probs = {}
for target_word, translations in word_translations.iteritems():
    total = float(sum(translations.values()))
    for source_word, score in translations.iteritems():
        conditional_probs[source_word, target_word] = score / total

return conditional_probs


def main():
    SENTENCES = [
            ('mi casa verde'.split(), 'my green house'.split()),
            ('casa verde'.split(), 'green house'.split()),
            ('la casa'.split(), 'the house'.split()),
            ]
    print em_run(SENTENCES)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Indentation is wrong. For example, what this line "for i, sentence_alignments in enumerate(alignments)" is supposed to do in "# Repeat until convergence"?

Comment: As far as I understand, all you want to do is to open two files and pass the content within to the `em_run()` function. It is not a difficult situation. Just look up how to open and read files in Python.

Comment: @Marcin It's part of a dict comprehension, but the rest of the indentation is broken

Answer (score 1):

If each file contains one part of the pair of sentences, and each line of the first file corresponds to the same line in the second, all you need to do is `open` the files and `zip` them together:

```
em_run(zip(open('file1'), open('file2')))
```

Comment: def em_run(zip(open('file1'), open('file2'))):
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax .                                                                                                       Actually file1 contain hundreds of sentences in English language and file2 contain hundreds of sentences in another language(Malayalam) .

Comment: You're trying to define the function with those as parameters but you don't need to change the function at all. You need to modify the `print em_sentences(...)` line in your `main` func.

Comment: @NiaMaryRose , I would use dictionary for it `{'sentense one': ['translate', 'sinonym1', 'sinonymN']}`

Comment: @MichaelKazarian Why? The `em_run` function takes a list of pairs, which is what `zip` is providing, what does putting them into such a structure gain?

Comment: @NiaMaryRose "Not working" isn't helpful. What error are you getting?

Comment: Not working in the sense, no error, but pointer is blinking and no output.

Comment: You're not really helping us help you. How did you run it? How familiar are you with Python?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "em1.py", line 131, in <module>
    main()
  File "em1.py", line 128, in main
    print em_run(zip(open('exercise2'), open('exercise3')))
  File "em1.py", line 44, in em_run
    for source, target in sentence_pairs] 
MemoryError

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways:

1. Use [persistence](https://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html). If you use this way you can save any object to some store i.g. file. But not always you can change it manually.
2. Write string representation to file and parse it. It good way for simple objects i.g. numbers, string, etc. but has manually parsing.

If you read data from files... Suppose it has below format:

**English**

```
my green house
green house
the house
```

**Malayalam**

```
mi casa verde
casa verde
la casa
```

Below your code, adapted for file instead `list`s.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from itertools import izip
from collections import defaultdict
import copy
import itertools
import operator


def em_run(sentence_pairs):
    #Run expectation-maximization on a list of pairs of the form
    # `(source_tokens, target_tokens)`
    # where `source_tokens` is a list of tokens in the source language and
    #`target_tokens` is a list of tokens for a translationally equivalent
    #sentence in the target language.
    #Returns a mapping `(t1, t2) => p` where `t1` is a source-language
    #token, `t2` is a target-language token, and the value `p` represents
    #$P(t1|t2)$.


    source_sentences, target_sentences = zip(*sentence_pairs)
    source_vocabulary = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(source_sentences))
    target_vocabulary = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(target_sentences))

    # Value with which to initialize each conditional probability
    uniform_prob = 1.0 / len(source_vocabulary)

    conditional_probs_old = None
    conditional_probs = {(source_w, target_w): uniform_prob
        for source_w in source_vocabulary
        for target_w in target_vocabulary}

    alignments = [[zip(source, target_perm)
        for target_perm in itertools.permutations(target)]
        for source, target in sentence_pairs] 

    # Repeat until convergence
    i = 0
    while conditional_probs_old != conditional_probs:
        conditional_probs_old = copy.copy(conditional_probs)

        alignment_probs = {
            i: {
                tuple(alignment):
                reduce(operator.mul, [conditional_probs[pair]
                    for pair in alignment])
                for alignment in sentence_alignments
           }

    for i, sentence_alignments in enumerate(alignments)
    }

    # Normalize alignment probabilities
    for sentence_idx, sentence_alignments in alignment_probs.iteritems():
        total = float(sum(sentence_alignments.values()))
        probs = {alignment: value / total
            for alignment, value in sentence_alignments.iteritems()}
        alignment_probs[sentence_idx] = probs

    # Now join all alignments and begin the maximization step: group
    # by target-language word and collect corresponding
    # source-language probabilities
    word_translations = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))
    for sentence_alignments in alignment_probs.itervalues():
        for word_pairs, prob in sentence_alignments.iteritems():
            for source_word, target_word in word_pairs:
                word_translations[target_word][source_word] += prob

    # Now calculate new conditional probability mapping, ungrouping
    # the `word_translations` tree and normalizing values into
    # conditional probabilities
    conditional_probs = {}
    for target_word, translations in word_translations.iteritems():
        total = float(sum(translations.values()))
        for source_word, score in translations.iteritems():
            conditional_probs[source_word, target_word] = score / total

    return conditional_probs


def main():
    SENTENCES = [
    ('mi casa verde'.split(), 'my green house'.split()),
    ('casa verde'.split(), 'green house'.split()),
    ('la casa'.split(), 'the house'.split()),
            ]
    print "Original SENTENCES"
    print "Original results" em_run(SENTENCES)
    print "******** Read words from files ********************"
    NEWSENTENCES = []
    with open("datafile_english") as textEn, open("datafile_malayalam") as textMal:
        for x, y in izip(textEn, textMal):
            x = x.strip().split()
            y = y.strip().split()
            NEWSENTENCES.append((y, x))
    print "NEWRESULT", em_run(NEWSENTENCES)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Original SENTENCES
Original results {('mi', 'green'): 0.16666666666666669, ('verde', 'my'): 0.3333333333333333, ('la', 'the'): 0.5, ('mi', 'my'): 0.3333333333333333, ('mi', 'house'): 0.1111111111111111, ('casa', 'the'): 0.5, ('casa', 'my'): 0.3333333333333333, ('verde', 'house'): 0.27777777777777773, ('casa', 'house'): 0.4444444444444444, ('casa', 'green'): 0.4166666666666667, ('verde', 'green'): 0.4166666666666667, ('la', 'house'): 0.16666666666666666}
**** Read words from file ************************
NEWRESULT {('mi', 'green'): 0.16666666666666669, ('verde', 'my'): 0.3333333333333333, ('la', 'the'): 0.5, ('mi', 'my'): 0.3333333333333333, ('mi', 'house'): 0.1111111111111111, ('casa', 'the'): 0.5, ('casa', 'my'): 0.3333333333333333, ('verde', 'house'): 0.27777777777777773, ('casa', 'house'): 0.4444444444444444, ('casa', 'green'): 0.4166666666666667, ('verde', 'green'): 0.4166666666666667, ('la', 'house'): 0.16666666666666666}
```

Comment: It sounds more like they already have the two files and want to feed them into the `em_run` function rather than the test data currently used.

Comment: But `em_run` takes a list of pairs, what does putting them into a dictionary gain you? You're also not showing how you're passing it into that function.

Comment: @NiaMaryRose, see update. I added samples of data files and solution for read it into storage. I prefer use `dictionary` storage, but you can use something else.

Comment: @Michael , invalid syntax for 'for loop'

Comment: I checked my sample, it work with `python2`. For `python3` replace `itertools.izip` with the built-in `zip`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "em1.py", line 131, in <module>
    main()
  File "em1.py", line 127, in main
    print em_run(myStorage)
  File "em1.py", line 23, in em_run
    source_sentences, target_sentences = izip(*sentence_pairs)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
.................................................................................................................I dont know what to do with this.....

Comment: See update. I have fixed indentation and updated your `main()` functions and obtained identical results.